# Unintelligent textboxes in VS2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a WinForm in a vb.net application. It has between 4 and 7 multiline textboxes. I want to be able to copy and paste information into or out of those textboxes but it appears to be impossible. There is no right-click cut copy or paste available and the keyboard shortcuts do not work either.

The properties of all textboxes are enabled, visible and have shortcuts enabled

Can anyone help please?

Comment: They might be RichTextBoxes, there is no default right click menu in RTB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create first a ContextMenuStrip.
2. Add new menuitem: 'Paste', set the menuItem's ShortcutKeys property to CTRL+V.
3. Set the (Rich)Textbox -> ContextMenuStrip property to created menu control.
4. Handle the 'Paste' menuitem click event.
5. Try the result.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be a strange problem.Make sure that  you are using the real textbox control and not some custom user control.
It is also possible that the changes you make in designer and code are not written into the exe.When you debug your project, you might be seeing an old version of your program in which the properties might be set to false. In that case you have to simply delete the exe in the bin\debug folder and rebuild your project.